Data Binding Not Displaying Dialog Title in Custom Dialog
am trying to create a custom dialog in my Android application using data binding. However, the dialogTitle is not displaying as expected. Here is the relevant code:
class CustomDialog(
    context: Context,
    private val dataList: ArrayList<MainDropDownModel>,
    private val dialogTitle: String,
    private val onItemSelected: (MainDropDownModel) -> Unit
) : Dialog(context) {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var dropdownAdapter: MainDropdownAdapter
    private val binding: ItemDropdownListBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.item_dropdown_list, null, false)

    init {
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.dialogTitle = dialogTitle
        binding.dialogCloseIcon.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}


<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="dialogTitle"
            type="String" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_round">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dialog_top"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_half_round"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/nanum_bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/main_black"
                android:text="@{dialogTitle}" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_close_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/assist_device_x_black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_RV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_top" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>

// Activity
        mainDropdownGroup.setOnClickListener {
            CustomDialog(this,groups, "Groups") { selectedItem ->
                mainDropdownGroup.text = selectedItem.device_title
            }.show()
        }

I am creating a custom dialog and passing the title "Groups" to it when calling from the activity.
What could be causing the dialogTitle to not display in the dialog?
Is there a missing step in the data binding process that I need to address?
